# Event handler is repeating an array on click

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom-events

I am creating something that adds an image to a gallery as a result of a user filling in a text field and clicking a button.

When a new image url is added, it adds to an array holding each image URL.

The problem is that the function that adds the image creates a new array each time a new image is added.

I'm trying to figure out how to add an image to the first array returned or remove the previous array.

Here is the HTML:

```
<header id="header">
  <h1 id="title">jgdGalleryMaker</h1>
  <div class="form">
    <label for="image_url">Image URL: </label>
    <input type="text" id="image_url" name="image_url" class="img-input" placeholder="Enter a URL for your gallery image">
    <button type="submit" class="btn img-submit-btn">Add an image to the gallery</button>
    
    <select name="mode" id="gallery-mode">
      <option>View Gallery</option>
      <option>Edit Gallery</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</header>
<div id="gallery-container">
  <div class="jgd-gallery">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

...and the JavaScript (so far):

```
let imgBtn = document.querySelector(".img-submit-btn");
let gallery = document.querySelector(".jgd-gallery");

let galImgsArray = [];

gallery.innerHTML = galImgsArray;

function addImgTile() {
  let imgURL = document.getElementById("image_url").value;
  galImgsArray.unshift(imgURL);
  console.log(galImgsArray);
  
  for (let i = 0; i < galImgsArray.length; i++) {
    gallery.innerHTML += '<figure class="jgd-gallery__image"><a href="' + galImgsArray[i] + '"><img src="' + galImgsArray[i] + '" /></a></figure>';
  }
}

imgBtn.addEventListener('click', addImgTile);
```

I'm working on this in the Codepen below as well:
[jgdGalleryMaker Codepen](https://codepen.io/jgpws/pen/MWeBjaW)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to clear out the HTML of the gallery before iterating over your array. The problem with your current solution, is that you are not adding 1 new image every time the button is clicked, instead you are adding the entire content of the array without overriding what is already there. The line `gallery.innerHTML = ''` is clearing the previous content before iterating over the array and adding every image to the gallery.

```
function addImgTile() {
  let imgURL = document.getElementById("image_url").value;
  galImgsArray.unshift(imgURL);
  console.log(galImgsArray);
  
  gallery.innerHTML = ''; // This line empty the inner HTML of this element
  for (let i = 0; i < galImgsArray.length; i++) {
    gallery.innerHTML += '<figure class="jgd-gallery__image"><a href="' + galImgsArray[i] + '"><img src="' + galImgsArray[i] + '" /></a></figure>';
  }
}
```

Comment: This works! It looks like this clears the previous array. Thank you for your solution.